# Class name of the NSView containing text attribute controls that IB adds to NSWindow

Tags: macos, text, attributes, controls, titlebar

When I add a NSTextView via IB, IB adds a string of text attribute controls below the window title.  It's a great feature, but it is aligned left not centered.  I'm trying to find documentation so I can center it.  But, I can't find any reference to it.

What is its class name?  Where is it documented?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you add a screenshot? The class name of an object in a XIB can usually be found in the Identity Inspector in the right side bar of Xcode after selecting the particular item.

Comment: Here is a link.  IB adds this "text attributes toolbar]  implicitly.  It is not shown on the IB canvas. [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/o543gmpi9wx7geb/Screen%20Shot%202017-11-29%20at%207.50.09%20AM.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "Inspector Bar". `NSTextView` has a property `usesInspectorBar` to enable/disable it.

The question is probably a duplicate if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100913/cocoa-how-to-reposition-inspector-bar) and it seems the bar cannot be tweaked.

Comment: Thanks.  It was the name "Inspector Bar" that was lacking in my knowledge.